# I am having an error 'no such file or directory' with using multer to upload images to server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

```
app.use(
  "/tmp/upload/images",
  express.static(path.join(__dirname, "tmp/upload/images"))
);
```

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, "/tmp/upload/images");
  },
  filename: (req, file, cb) => {
    return cb(
      null,
      `${file.fieldname}_${Date.now()}${path.extname(file.originalname)}`
    );
  },
});
const upload = multer({
  storage: storage,
});
```

`Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory`
I am having this error when trying to add images on Heroku server. `tmp/upload/images` directory exists on the repo but still having issues

I think the server is not configured correctly for static files. Can anyone help with this?

Comment: I'm sure Heroku doesn't allow writes on its filesystem.

Comment: it does for some minutes as a temporary storage.

Comment: I am also trying this on cyclic but getting same error

Comment: they get reset daily and on every deployment.

Comment: maybe you should try upload or host images somewhere else and use that links to view.

Comment: I am doing the same as you are saying. I am uploading to s3 but I have to keep the files on the server to resize them.  After that I am deleting them from server